# nginx-noscript blocking Facebook IPs

Tags: linux, facebook, firewall, noscript, fail2ban

I have fail2ban configured in my server against noscript. However i have some widgets to share content to facebook.

Now I am receiving this alert:

```
The IP 31.13.102.103 has just been banned by Fail2Ban after
6 attempts against nginx-noscript.

Abuse contact for '31.13.102.0 - 31.13.102.255' is 'domain@fb.com'
```

So, the question is, should I remove the rule or ignore this message? As far as i can see the content is shared anyway. But I am not sure about the correct action here.

---

```
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php
```

rule:

```
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = nginx-noscript
logpath  = /usr/local/nginx/localhost-access.log
maxretry = 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove that rule.  If you don't, the Facebook crawler isn't going to be able to load page titles, descriptions, and thumbnails.

Comment: ok, but I need more details. I don't have many shares, so, If facebook only do this requests when a new post is made, I do't need to worry. Or, can I just disable this rule without any major concern in terms of security?

Comment: @anvd It may change over time.  Without seeing your actual rule and access log it's hard to give specific advice, but this rule sounds overly paranoid to me.